# Add CSS to Joomla 1.7 Admin Area of Module

Tags: css, joomla, module, admin

I've been searching for days and can't seem to find the answer (if there is an answer). I know how to add style and scripts to the front end of Joomla from a module(addStyle() and addScript()), but I can't seem to find out how to add a stylesheet or script file to the admin section of Joomla from a module.

I know you can add a class in the xml file, but how do you access them. I could ftp the stylesheet or script and then edit the template files, but I want to be able to include those things when the module loads. Does anyone know how to do that? Or is it even possible?

Or can I add the style through the XML? I know I can manipulate the label by adding styles, but not the textbox,listbox,etc.

I'm using Joomla 1.7, but would like to know for 1.5 as well. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Thanks for your help! This is driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same in 1.5, 1.7 and 2.5. Have a look at:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_11

You simply add the declaration to your method in your admin view.html.php file.

In fact, it's exactly the same as adding it to your frontend view, you just add it to your admin view instead.